# what does the count method (without argument) in Python count?

Tags: python

I tried count method in Python like this.

```
 greet="Hello Python"
 greet.count("")
```

**The answer is 13. Why?**

Number of characters in object 'greet'? But len(greet)=12.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to count the number of characters in a string, use the built-in `len('your_string')` method. It will give you an answer of `12`.

`.count()` is used to count the number of occurrences of something in a list. If you wanted to know how many times the letter 'l' occurs in your list, for example, then `greet.count('l')` would give you the correct answer of 2.

So my guess is your code is trying to count the number of times an empty string occurs in your text, and apparently the answer is 13.